# Architecture for a drawer layout app

Tags: java, android

I am building an app with a drawer layout similar to the Android Facebook app. I am wondering what the best method for architecture is. Should I have a main activity which is responsible for the action bar, and then have it use fragments to display the content of each menu item, or should I be using one activity to manage the action bar, and then have each menu item kick off entirely separate activities?

I could also imagine building multiple activities, which each have to manage the action bar. This option seems the worst.

Comment: Does any of the following answers help you ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two architecture options here

`MainActivity` with `Fragments`

`ParentActivity` that handles drawer and lots of `Activities` that extends this `Activity`.

I have tried both in different projects and found some things worth sharing.

For me The `MainActivity` that handles drawer and then using `Fragments` to fill the display is the best.
You will need to handle callbacks from specific `Fragments` in your `MainActivity` and redirect them to the specific `Fragment` they came from. This is mainly if you use `Interfaces` in objects lower in the Arcitecture chain since you sometimes need to pass down `Activity` to certain objects. This generates more code that are not as generic as one might want in top level architecture node.
If you are using a `ParentActivity` and extending it for each `ChildActivity`,  you can write all specific code in the child, meaning that the toplevel `ParentActivity` will almost only have generic code.

If you are using the `ParentActivity` with `ChildActivities` and you are switching between `Activities`, you fill get the graphic when an `Activity` closes and the next opens every time a user switches between navigation objects. If you use `Fragments` this wont happen as the `Fragment` will be switched in the background. The user will also experience that the navigation drawer will be closed and recreated each time he clicks on an item there.
Its also unnessecary to recreate the navigation drawer with each click on an item. This is a minus for the `ParentActivity` approach.

With the `ParentActivity` approach you will also have to keep track of how the `backbutton` should function, this will be autoaticly handled for you with `Fragments`. Also when starting new `Activities` you have to choose if a new `Activity` should be created or if the old should be killed etc.

Just my 5c, hopes it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, yours was the only answer that provided more content and explanation rather than links so +50 to you.

Comment: Thanks, and if I wasnt clear enough in my answer: I recommend the Fragment method.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use one `Activity` with one `Fragment` per section/view.

Take a look at the [design documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).

Also see the [Tutorial and Sample Application](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). It's fairly straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the activity holding the actionbar & drawer
When using a drawer you should not start new activities from within the drawer but fragment instead

Good post & video about it: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RomanNurik/posts/3nMVVQzUTjG

another good read: http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2013/05/the-new-navigation-drawer-pattern.html

And finally this is a must see also (check the slides or the video): https://plus.google.com/u/0/+NickButcher/posts/1jeyV2n1ZpM

Answer (score 0):

You will have one activity which manages ActionBar, Drawer (ListView!) and Fragment.

Every time it clicks an item in the ListView it updates the fragment with the new view.

If you use different Activities then you should use intents with a very bad effect, use a different activity only if needed (if it's totally unrelated to the current activity maybe?)

Official documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

If you got any problem in creating this, online you can found more tutorials but the official is very great.